# Insert multiple rows, where all the values of column of insert statement are same except one column

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I am inserting multiple entries into a table. The values of all column of insert statement are same except for one column. This particular column takes values serially from an excel file as shown in the program. I cannot get an idea of how to pass this incremental value to the insert query using cx_Oracle module.

I tried using bind concept  as shown in code but nothing fruitful, please suggest.

```py
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\ABHISHEK.POUDEL\Desktop\mmyyyy.xlsx')

import cx_Oracle
con=cx_Oracle.connect('system/manager1@192.168.8.72:1521/SANUPS')
cur=con.cursor()

print(con.version)


print(df.head(5))

x=df.head(5)
size=x.size
sql="""Insert into tbaadm.hol (CAL_B2K_TYPE,CAL_B2K_ID,MMYYYY,DEL_FLG,HLDY_STR,COMMENT_STR,RECVD_STR,STATUS,LCHG_USER_ID,LCHG_TIME,RCRE_USER_ID,RCRE_TIME,TS_CNT,BANK_ID)
    VALUES ('BRANCH','910',:1,'N',null,null,null,' ','SYSTEM',to_date('25-JUL-19','DD-MON-YY'),'SYSTEM',to_date('25-JUL-19','DD-MON-RR'),0,'01')"""

def insert_func(val):
    val=str(val)
    #cur.execute(sql,(val))
    cur.execute("""Insert into tbaadm.hol (CAL_B2K_TYPE,CAL_B2K_ID,MMYYYY,DEL_FLG,HLDY_STR,COMMENT_STR,RECVD_STR,STATUS,LCHG_USER_ID,LCHG_TIME,RCRE_USER_ID,RCRE_TIME,TS_CNT,BANK_ID)
    VALUES ('BRANCH','910',:1,'N',null,null,null,' ','SYSTEM',to_date('25-JUL-19','DD-MON-YY'),'SYSTEM',to_date('25-JUL-19','DD-MON-RR'),0,'01'), val""")
    return

for f in range(size):
    print(f)
    print(df.iloc[f])
    insert_func(df.iloc[f])


con.commit()
con.close()


11.2.0.2.0
   MMYYYY
0  122099
1  122098
2  122097
3  122096
4  122095
0
MMYYYY    122099
Name: 0, dtype: int64
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\AVI\PYTHON\KOMODO_FILES\create_date_daily_files.py", line 40, in <module>
    insert_func(df.iloc[f])
  File "D:\AVI\PYTHON\KOMODO_FILES\create_date_daily_files.py", line 34, in insert_func
    VALUES ('BRANCH','910',:1,'N',null,null,null,' ','SYSTEM',to_date('25-JUL-19','DD-MON-YY'),'SYSTEM',to_date('25-JUL-19','DD-MON-RR'),0,'01'), val""")
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the parameter to the execute, as in:

```
cursor.execute(sql, [val])
```

or

```
cursor.execute(sql, (val,))
```

Comment: cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12899: value too large for column "TBAADM"."HOLIDAY_MAST_TABLE"."MMYYYY" (actual: 38, maximum: 6)

Comment: above error was generated, i think your suggested solution tries to insert a list of val variable all at once into the table.

Comment: Not at all! The error suggests that the data is invalid for your table -- that you are trying to bind something more than 6 characters (in your case 38 characters) into the column!